Why does my control trigger a clicked on event when it is created?
I have a control that should do something when clicked on, to achieve this I connected its mouseclick event to a function on creation but the problem is that the click event Is triggered even tho my mouse is not clicking it(My mouse is not even on the form???)
Here is the code behind it=>
//View form
public partial class View : Form
{
    
    DataAccesObject accesObject = new DataAccesObject();
    string ControlTitle;
    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        accesObject.Collection = accesObject.GetAllCollection();// gets all the series in my SQL database
       
        for (int i = 0; i < accesObject.Collection.Count; i++) //creates a new panel for each series
        {
            
           AddPanels(accesObject.Collection[i]);
          
        }
        
    }

    private void Mouseclicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
       SeriePage page = new SeriePage();//opens up a page for the clicked series
        page.Title = ControlTitle;//series get searched up on the other form for more information
        page.Show();
        

        
    }

    private void AddTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TagBox.Items.Add(TagInput.Text);
        TagInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void RemoveTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TagBox.Items.Remove(TagInput.Text);
        TagInput.Text = string.Empty;

    }

    
    private void AddPanels(DataClass Data)
    {
        SeriesPanel seriesPanel = new SeriesPanel();//creates a new seriespanel user control
        seriesPanel.ImageLocation = Data.C_Image;
        seriesPanel.Title = Data.C_Title;
        this.Controls.Add(seriesPanel);//adds to the current form
       seriesPanel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Mouseclicked);//connects to the mouseclick function
        
    }
}



 

Seriespanel code:
 public partial class SeriesPanel : UserControl
 {
     public SeriesPanel()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private string _ImageLocation;
     private string _Title;
     private Image _Icon;
     [Category("Custom Props")]
     public string ImageLocation
     {
         get { return _ImageLocation; }
         set { _ImageLocation = value; PanelImage.ImageLocation = value; }
     }
     [Category("Custom Props")]
     public string Title
     {
         get { return _Title; }
         set { _Title = value; PanelLabel.Text = value; }

     }
     [Category("Custom Props")]
     public Image Icon
     {
         get { return _Icon; }
         set { _Icon = value; PanelImage.Image = value; }
     }
 }

I wasn't able to input an image so just imagine a white background, with an empty picture box and a label on top of it.

seriesPanel.MouseClick += Mouseclicked(Data.C_Title);  <-- This will invoke Mouseclicked - rather than wire-it-up. Your Mouseclicked should not return MouseEventHandler - and having return null is even worse...

BTW, you might be tempted to do seriesPanel.MouseClick += ( s, e ) => this.Mouseclicked( Data.C_Title ); but this will result in a nasty resource-leak because it's an anonymous function so you can't remove the event-handler once it's added.

@Dai It will be disposed along with the form.

@rotabor We don't know that, the OP hasn't posted enough code. It's very easy to leak memory with event delegates in WinForms when using events non-idiomatically.

@Dai Do you have anything to say on the subject? Some specific events can be recalled during object initialization, but not MouseClick.

@rotabor I don't know what you mean by "Some specific events can be recalled during object initialization"

You need to look for Mouseclicked calls. Why is it public??? MouseClick should not be called by anything other than a mouse click.


Store Data.C_Title in a field somewhere, and reference that field inside your Mouseclicked event-handler.

And Mouseclicked needs to conform to MouseEventHandler, i.e. private void Mouseclicked(Object? sender, EventArgs e).


Wire-up seriesPanel.MouseClick correctly:

If your event-handlers will be added only once, inside the ctor (after InitialzieComponent), then you can use seriesPanel.MouseClick += this.Mouseclicked (this creates a delegate variable behind-the-scenes and passes that to the MouseClick multicast delegate).
If your event-handlers are dynamic (added and removed at runtime) then you need to use += and -= with a MouseEventHandler-typed variable rather than the method-name itself.


Also, are you sure you want MouseClick instead of Click? Consider using Click instead of MouseClick where-possible for accessibility reasons.


Like so:
(I've renamed the Mouseclicked method to OnSeriesPanelClicked for clarity)
void Somewhere( ... )
{
    this.title = Data.C._Title;

    // called on creation (I create my control through code so doing it manually wont work)
    seriesPanel.MouseClick += this.OnSeriesPanelClicked;
}

private String? title;

public void OnSeriesPanelClicked(Object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SeriePage page = new SeriePage();
    page.Title = this.title;
    page.Show();
}


For added/removed event-handlers (and assuming you'll be using different handler methods than just OnSeriesPanelClicked):
(For clarity, this code is more verbose than it needs to be)
void Somewhere( ... )
{
    if( this.lastMouseClick != null )
    {
        seriesPanel.MouseClick -= this.lastMouseClickHandler;
        this.lastMouseClickHandler = null;
    }

    this.title = Data.C._Title;

    MouseEventHandler newHandler = new MouseEventHandler( this.OnSeriesPanelClicked );
    seriesPanel.MouseClick += newHandler;
    this.lastMouseClickHandler = newHandler;
}

private MouseEventHandler? lastMouseClickHandler;

private String? title;

public void OnSeriesPanelClicked(Object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SeriePage page = new SeriePage();
    page.Title = this.title;
    page.Show();
}


Lets just say that this didnt work out for me,Do you know any resources that I can go through to understand this better?

@NEWBIE Please edit your question to show us more context, especially exactly how you're creating and using seriesPanel.

Okay, i have edited it,some things are changed as I tried to find a way to fix it. The problem right know is that the click is not working but at least the forced click problem is gone

@NEWBIE Your code looks fine to me - my guess is that there's something wrong in class SeriesPanel. Please post that to your question.

@NEWBIE It's possible the PanelImage control inside SeriesPanel is getting the mouse-click message and not bubbling it up to SeriesPanel.

Instead of adding Mouseclicked as an event handler, you're calling Mouseclicked and adding what it returns, in this case null as a handler. Removing the (Data.C_Title) is what you want, though it will expose a different problem in this case.
Almost all (if not all) WinForms event handlers are expected to have arguments of (object sender, System.EventArgs e) where EventArgs might be replaced with another class inheriting from EventArgs. So MouseClicked needs to be changed to have those parameters.
